# May I use not to have here?

Tags: writing

I like to use `not to have` but it sounds strange here:

> Comming from Brazil, a country lucky enough not to have hurricanes, tornadoes, volcanic eruptions, earthquakes and tsunamis, perhaps necessity for such a center was not clear.

Is it correct?

Comment: No, it isn't. The part after the comma is wrong. Also, try need rather than necessity. Comming takes one m  only.

Comment: You use 'not to have' correctly.  As Lambie points out, however, the end of your sentence is not constructed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

[The Cambridge Dictionary website](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/questions-and-negative-sentences/negation) says it's fine.

> Non-finite clauses are clauses without a subject, where the main verb is in the to-infinitive form, the -ing form or the -ed form. To make the negative of a non-finite clause, we can use not.
>
> Not to have invited James to our little party would have been impolite.

However, to me personally, **to not have** sounds better.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite `not to have` in the sentence as `to have not experienced`, meaning it would read like so:

> Comming from Brazil, a country lucky enough to have not experienced hurricanes, tornadoes, volcanic eruptions, earthquakes, and tsunamis, perhaps the necessity for such a center was not clear.